# bash: hit return once, run 2 commands in the background

Tags: bash, shell, background-process

Rather than this:

```
$ command1 & 
$ command2 & 
$ …
```

Is there a way to do the equivalent in bash, but on a single line of input?

Comment: Exactly that but hit space after the first `&` instead of enter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&` is a command terminator, just like `;`. You can include multiple commands on one line.

```
$ command1 & command2 &
$
```

Comment: I’m a little surprised I never tried this…!  Thank you. :)